# How to find the relationship between two categorical variables that are in the same column of a dataframe using Pandas and Scipy?

Tags: python, pandas, scipy, statistics, correlation

I have a dataframe with an 'EVENT' column that has three variables called click, pageview and preview. I want to check for any correlation between clicks and previews on a link? If there is, is it significant and how large is the effect? And I want to test for potential linear and binary relationships between the two variables.

A random sample showing my dataframe columns and entries is shown below.
[image]

I tried the following codes using the Pandas corr() method but none of them worked.

```
pageviews = df.loc[df.event == 'pageview']
clicks = df.loc[df.event == 'click']
pageviews.corr(clicks)
```

I got the following error message when I ran this code:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

And when I ran corr() method on the entire column as shown below:

```
df['event'].corr()
```

I get the following error message

```
TypeError: corr() missing 1 required positional argument: 'other'
```

My question is, using Pandas or Scipy how could I possibly check if there is a correlation or relationship between click and pageview categories in the event column as shown in the dataframe above? And how do I test for the statistical significance of the relationship if there is any?

Comment: You can't run a correlation test on a column and itself. Are you trying to correlate the number of clicks/pageviews per link? If so, you can do something like `df.groupby('linkid')['event'].value_counts().unstack()[['pageview', 'click']].corr()`. This looks at the correlation between the number of clicks/pageviews on a PER LINK basis, which is a key step.

Comment: @BrianJoseph I think that solution looks as if that is what I am trying to do. I am being asked to test for the correlation between the click and pageview event on links. I will try out your approach.